# Image Caching Issue In Xamarin Android

Tags: android, image, caching, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am working on Xamarin Android Application.To Cache the Images I have included this packages:
`MvvmCross.HotTuna.Plugin.DownloadCache`
`MvvmCross.HotTuna.Plugin.File`
`MvvmCross.HotTuna.Plugin.Json`

My BootStrap Files are,

```
using Cirrious.CrossCore.Plugins;
namespace Main.Droid.Bootstrap
 {
   public class DownloadCachePluginBootstrap
    :   MvxPluginBootstrapAction<Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.DownloadCache.PluginLoader>
      {
      }
  }




using Cirrious.CrossCore.Plugins;
namespace Main.Droid.Bootstrap
 {
    public class FilePluginBootstrap
    : MvxPluginBootstrapAction<Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.File.PluginLoader>
      {
      }
  }



using Cirrious.CrossCore.Plugins;
namespace Main.Droid.Bootstrap
 {
    public class JsonPluginBootstrap
    : MvxPluginBootstrapAction<Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Json.PluginLoader>
        {
        }
 }
```

And This is how I download Image from Internet:

```
private void GetImageBitmapFromUrlAsync(string url)
    {
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.DownloadDataCompleted += delegate(object sender, DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Result != null && e.Result.Length > 0)
            {
                var options = new BitmapFactory.Options
                {
                    InJustDecodeBounds = false,
                };
                // BitmapFactory.DecodeResource() will return a non-null value; dispose of it.
                using (var dispose = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(e.Result,0, e.Result.Length, options))                    
                    imageview.SetImageBitmap(dispose);                  
            }
        };
        webClient.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri(url));

    }
```

My Problem is Images are not being cached.What am I doing wrong ? Any Solution ? Please Help !

Comment: Why aren't you using automatic data binding?

Have you tried creating property (e.g. `Image`) in `ViewModel` and bind it to the view in .xml file?
Like this: `local:MvxBind="ImageUrl Image"`

Comment: HI,misho,I am binding the image like you said but It can not cache the image.What should I do ? @misho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way for handling images without concerning cache, delay or retry of a download of an image, transformation, speed and more (because all of those are handled automatically) is [Picasso](https://components.xamarin.com/view/square.picasso).
Once you try it you will never come back.